# Python ordering rules for arguments passing in a function call

Tags: python

I tried to use * and ** to pass any number of arguments to a function. In "Learning Python" authored by Mark Lutz, it says to follow the order of positional (value) first, then a combination of keyword arguments (name=value) and *sequence, followed by **dict. However, I found that the positional arguments need to come first if present, but the rest of three, to certain extent, can be mixed in order. 
Code keywords3.py:

```
def     func(a, b=1, *pArgs, **kwArgs): 
        print("a = {0}, b = {1}".format(a,b))
        print("Positional args = {}".format(pArgs))
        print("Keyword args = {}".format(kwArgs))
```

By trial-and-error,

[1] Between keywords and **dict, they can be in any order...

```
>>> import keywords3 as j

>>> j.func(b = 3, **{'a':2,'c':4,'d':5})
a = 2, b = 3
Positional args = ()
Keyword args = {'d': 5, 'c': 4}
>>> j.func( **{'a':2}, b = 3, **{'c':4})
a = 2, b = 3
Positional args = ()
Keyword args = {'c': 4}
```

[2] Between positional args and *sequence, they can be in any order...

```
>>> j.func(*(2, 3), 4, *(5, 6))
a = 2, b = 3
Positional args = (4, 5, 6)
Keyword args = {}
>>> j.func(2, *(3, 4), 5, *(6,7), **{'c':8})
a = 2, b = 3
Positional args = (4, 5, 6, 7)
Keyword args = {'c': 8}
```

[3] In general, positional or *sequence arguments need to appear before keyword or **dict arguments.

```
>>> j.func(*(3, 4), 5, *(6,7), d=15, **{'c':8}, e=16)
a = 3, b = 4
Positional args = (5, 6, 7)
Keyword args = {'e': 16, 'd': 15, 'c': 8}

>>> j.func(d=15, 5, *(6,7), **{'c':8}, e=16)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

>>> j.func(**{'a':2}, 5, *(6,7), **{'c':8}, e=16)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument unpacking

>>> j.func(**{'a':2}, *(6,7), **{'c':8}, e=16)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: iterable argument unpacking follows keyword argument unpacking
```

[4] One exception is that iterable argument unpacking *(6,7) following keyword argument is ok...

```
>>> j.func(f=5, *(6,7), **{'c':8}, e=16)
a = 6, b = 7
Positional args = ()
Keyword args = {'e': 16, 'f': 5, 'c': 8}
```

Are these observations correct? Please comment.

Comment: The grammar rules are available at: https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions

Comment: You confuse list/dictionary unpacking that happens at the time of function call, and parameter lists/dictionaries that are used at the time of function definition. Both use the same notation (* and **) but have a totally different meaning. For example, `f(*(1,2),3)` is expanded to `f(1,2,3)`. 1 and 2 are still positional arguments. Likewise, `f(**{'c':8},e=16)` becomes `f(c=8,e=16)`, two named arguments.

Answer (score 3):

There is *one single rule* consistent with all your examples: positional arguments go before named arguments.

In all your examples, `*` and `**` are *unpacking* operators. So, for example, when you write

```
f(1, *(2,3), 4)
```

the language gets

```
f(1,2,3,4)
```

They are *all positional* arguments, the language doesn't know the difference. Similarly for the `**` operator.

However, when you violate that only rule, eg

```
j.func(**{'a':2}, 5, *(6,7), **{'c':8}, e=16)
```

you get an error, becuase, in this example, `**{'a':2}` is equivalent to `a=2`, which precedes the positional argument `5`.

Comment: Not quite. `f(a=1, *b)` has a keyword argument before a `*` unpacking, but it's allowed. It means the same thing as the more intuitive `f(*b, a=1)`, and `f(*b, a=1)` used to be disallowed.

Comment: Thanks all for the excellent explanations. What @user2357112 said about f(a=1, *b) being allowed is what I observed in [4] exception. Compared with f(**a, *b) which is not allowed due to the 'single rule', this kind of breaks the one single rule. True?

Comment: @LeonChang: the language *somehow* has to know which value corresponds to which variable. In this case, it works because your named argument happens to be the first one. Still, I would think that this would give an error (and I bet, so would many other python programmers). Regardless of what is valid, readability matters, so don't do it. Use either `*` when a function really accepts a collection of items, or `**` when you really have a dict/json-like object coming from some other function. Avoid using both, and, in most cases, don't use either.